# How to create multiple UIWebViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have Objective-C code for a `UIWebView` but I don't know how to use it to create multiple other `UIWebView`s.

Here's the code from the ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test22.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

How can I use this code to create other `UIWebView`s and how will I specify the different `UIWebView`s in the storyboard?

Comment: Why do you have a private outlet named `webView` (which you don't seem to use) as well as using a local variable named `webview` creating a `UIWebView` in code?

Comment: @rmaddy I don't know, I found the code from a tutorial and it worked. Maybe you could help me use another code for the uiwebview